# Test Chrome-only APIs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm new to Chrome extension development and I'm trying to debug the [`chrome.notifications`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) API.

Alas, when I try to use the console to test the API, I get the error that:

```
> chrome.notifications
undefined
```

I guess I need to test `chrome.notifications` in the context of an extension. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @milssner do you mind accepting this answer if it worked for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get access to the Chrome extension APIs you'll need to setup and install a barebones extension with the correct permissions.

- Manifest info: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest
- Permissions info:
  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

You'll need a manifest.json with something like below:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "short_name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "foo bar",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
  },
  "permissions": ["notifications"],
 }
```

As well as an empty `index.html`. Once you load your unpacked extension in the `chrome://extensions` page you'll be able to inspect the popup `index.html` and test out the notifications api in the inspector console.

As @abraham mentioned below another option would be to use a background script. You can do this by adding this object to `manifest.json`:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

In order to open the dev tools for the background page you'll need to click the `background page` link of your extension found in `chrome://extensions`.

Comment: It would probably be easier to use an empty background.js script so you don't have to worry about popups closing.

Comment: @abraham I think it's a matter of preference and also what the specific use case is. I personally find it easier to use the popup as there is no need to click `refresh` on any change.

Comment: If you have the background.js dev tools highlighted you can hit cmd+r/windows equivalent to refresh.

Comment: Hmm I guess its roughly the same. With the popup as long as the dev tools window is open the popup also stays locked/open.